# How to distinguish `approve` methods in ERC20 and ERC721

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js, erc-721, eip

In my app, I need to parse user transaction `data` and show users what's going on. Now the problem is, ERC20 and ERC721 both have an `approve` method, even with the same interface: `approve(address,uint256)`. But their second argument have different meanings: in ERC20, it means the max amount approved, in ERC721, it's the token ID approved. So how can I distinguish these two methods?

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the data you can't. You have to consider the contract in question and only then you'll know what the context is.

Sadly the ERC20 standard doesn't specify how to check whether a contract is an ERC20 contract. But the ERC721 one does with ERC165. You can read more about it for example [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/introspection).

Comment: Thanks, that's my current solution.